# TACACS+ Server is not returning av-pairs in authorization response

Tags: security, authentication, authorization, freebsd

I have TACACS+ Server(tac_plus version F4.0.4.28) running on Cent OS and the user configuration in tac_plus.conf looks like this.

```
user = test_user1 {
 default service = permit
 global = cleartext "password"
 service = exec {
   User-Group="sv_service"
 }
}

user = test_user2 {
  default service = permit
  global = cleartext "password"
  service = exec {
    priv_lvl=7
  }
}
```

I am using [Ansible TACACS Client](https://github.com/ansible/tacacs_plus) to authenticate & authorize users. Although both authentication and authorization are passed, TACACS+ server is not returning the av-pairs (User-Group for test_user1 & priv_lvl for test_user2).

```
[root@<machine_ip> ~]# tacacs_client -u test_user1 -H <tacacs_server_ip> -t pap -v authorize -c service=exec
tacacs+ shared key:
status: PASS

[root@<machine_ip> ~]# tacacs_client -u test_user2 -H <tacacs_server_ip> -t pap -v authorize -c service=exec
tacacs+ shared key:
status: PASS
```

Ideally success response should look like

```
tacacs+ shared key:
status: PASS
av-pairs:
  priv_lvl=7
```

Comment: Why is this tagged FreeBSD?

Comment: tac_plus version F4.0.4.28 is a FreeBSD distribution